# Isometry of a metric space example

Tags: metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, isometry

I am looking for an example of metric space isometry where the distance functions are different. I know one example of isometry would be a specific function where we have two metric spaces, both of them sets of real numbers and both having the distance function $f(x,y) = |x - y|$. I can see how some function $\sigma$ would be an isometry on those two metric spaces.

Can anyone provide an example of an isometric function on two distinct metric spaces with distinct distance functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On $(0,\infty)$, let $d_1(x,y)=\bigl\lvert\log(x)-\log(y)\bigr\rvert$ and on $\mathbb R$ let $d_2(x,y)=\lvert x-y\rvert$. Then$$\begin{array}{ccc}\bigl((0,\infty),d_1\bigr)&\longrightarrow&(\mathbb R,d_2)\\x&\mapsto&\log x\end{array}$$is an isometry.

Comment: Isn't $(0,\infty)$ just the natural numbers? Why the interval notation?

Comment: The notation $(0,\infty)$ stands for the set of all real numbers greater than $0$.

Answer (score 2):

You can for instance, starting from a vector space $E$ with norm $\|\mkern2mu.\|$ and a positive number $r$, consider $E$ with norm  $\|\mkern2mu.\|_r= r\|\kern2mu.\|$. The linear map:
\begin{align}
(E,\|\kern2mu.\|)&\longrightarrow (E,\|\kern2mu.\|_r)\\
x& \longmapsto \frac x r,
\end{align}
is such an isometry.

Comment: What exactly are the two distinct metrics here? Norm can't be defined as a metric on a metric space because a norm just takes one element and gives a real number, right?

Comment: The metrics associated to the norms $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$. A norm gives a *nonnegative* real number.

Comment: And what is the metric for the second vector space you specified?

Comment: Specifically what does this mean $\|\mkern2mu.\|_r= r(E,\|\kern2mu.\|)$?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo (wrong copy-paste, and forgot to check before posting). Fixed now. Thank you for pointing it!

Comment: Do all normed vector spaces have as its metric this same function $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$?

Comment: It's the definition of the associated metric. This  does not exclude other metrics, of course.